# Find headings and then modify them

Tags: c#, regex

How do I modify all matching headings from:

```
<h1>Some heading!</h1>
```

to

```
<h1 id="Someheading">Some heading!</h1>
```

The matching regex is

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<[hH]([1-3])>(.+?)</[hH][1-3]>");
```

and the trimming is made by

```
Regex.Replace(heading.Title, @"[\W]", "")
```

But how do I combine the two?

Comment: Have a look at Html Agility Pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: HtmlAgilityPack is nice, but overkill for this project. All headings will be well-formed so regex should be sufficient / best approach.

Comment: It can be done by a single line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this doesn’t look pretty, but it works. You should probably refactor it by extracting some of the nested conversions into separate methods.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<(h[1-3])>(?<val>.+?)</\1>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);  
string html = "<h1>Some heading!</h1>";

var result = regex.Replace(html, match => 
    match.Value.Insert(3, string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", 
        Regex.Replace(match.Groups["val"].Value, @"\W+", ""))));
```

I’ve fixed your original regex such that:

- it becomes case insensitive
- it defines a named subexpression, `val`, for matching the inner text of the element
- the end tag must match the start tag through a backreference, `\1`, thereby preventing matches such as `<h1>Hello</h2>`

Then, I’m applying the regex to your HTML document (which may contain any number of `h1`–`h3` elements). For every match, I’m inserting a new string within the start tag (right after the `<h1`) which is equivalent to `id="…"`, where the `…` is the inner text of your element with all non-word characters removed (through the application of an *inner* regex).

**Edit**: `RegexOptions.Singleline` added to match headings spanning multiple lines, per w0lf’s observation.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Deleted my own answer. I just used a separate method instead.

Comment: I hadn’t seen your answer, but maybe using separate methods isn’t a bad idea. The above, although a single-liner, is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Nice answer either way. Didn't know that matches could be aliased.

Comment: Yups, they’re called [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), or [named matched subexpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) in .NET. They’re particularly useful because you can have any number of groups and any number of captures within a single match.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do this, then I really think HtmlAgilityPack is *not* overkill.

It's just a ~130K dll and it will allow you to do this instead:

```
const string someHtml = "<h1>Some heading!</h1>\r\n" +
                        "<h2>Some sub-heading!</h2>\r\n" +
                        "<p> Some text in here</p>\r\n" +
                        "<h3> Another heading, this time\r\n" +
                        "spanning two rows</3>\r\n";

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDocument.LoadHtml(someHtml);

htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1")
.Union(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2"))
.Union(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3"))
.ToList()
.ForEach(node => node.Attributes.Add("id", 
    new string(node.InnerText.ToCharArray()
                  .Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray())));

Console.WriteLine(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

The code above produces:

```
<h1 id="Someheading">Some <a href="http://somelink">heading</a>!</h1>
<h2 id="Somesubheading">Some sub-heading!</h2>
<p> Some text in here</p>
<h3 id="Anotherheadingthistimespanningtworows"> Another heading, this time
spanning two rows</h3>
```

I think this code is relatively easy to produce and to understand, and it handles cases like:

- nested tags
- tags that span multiple lines
- empty tags

that can be pretty scary, if not impossible to handle with Regex.

Comment: While @Douglas's answer is very interesting and elegantly concise (+1 BTW) I would still avoid to do it because it has a high potential to intimidate developers with less Regex experience and because it's not as safe as the HtmlAgilityPack way (for example, it does not work for tags that span multiple lines - although I'm sure Douglas can fix that as well ;-) )

Comment: I have edited my code to generate the correct values for the `id` attributes

Comment: @w0lf: In general, I completely agree with you. I was assuming that this was a controlled scenario where the poster has control over the source data, or assurance that it will always be homogeneous. Another flaw of my regex is that it will fail if the start tag already contains attributes.

Comment: @Douglas: The HTML is generated through markdown, hence it's fully controlled.